# Solve over-determined system of linear equations

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, least-squares

I have a rather simple system of equations of the form:

```
1*A + 0*B + x2*C + y2*D = x1
0*A + 1*B + y2*C + x2*D = y1
```

where the pairs `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` are known floats of length `N` (the system is over-determined), and I need to solve for the `A, B, C, D` parameters.

I've been playing around with [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq) but I can't seem to get the shapes of the matrices right. This is what I have

```
import numpy as np

N = 10000
x1, y1 = np.random.uniform(0., 5000., (2, N))
x2, y2 = np.random.uniform(0., 5000., (2, N))

# 1*A + 0*B + x2*C + y2*D = x1
# 0*A + 1*B + y2*C + x2*D = y1

l1 = np.array([np.ones(N), np.zeros(N), x2, y2])
l2 = np.array([np.zeros(N), np.ones(N), y2, x2])

M1 = np.array([l1, l2])
M2 = np.array([x1, y1])

ABCD = np.linalg.lstsq(M1, M2)[0]
print(ABCD)
```

which fails with:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 3-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping everything else fixed, changing `M1` and `M2` to

```
M1 = np.vstack([l1.T, l2.T])
M2 = np.concatenate([x1, y1])
```

should do the job.

Comment: Nice! I thought about concatenating all those columns but this is much shorter thus better :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your concatenation is an issue and also the parameters for lstsq() have to be transposed.

```
M1 = np.hstack((l1,l2))
M2 = np.hstack((x1,x2))
ABCD = np.linalg.lstsq(M1.T,M2.T)[0]
```